# ToolBar on top of keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitextfield, uitoolbar, uikeyboard

How can i show toolbar with "Next" and "Previous" buttons on top of the keyboard on iPad like in ShareKit(when logging in)? I have many of text fields, and i need switching between this text fields by using toolbar buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Design your toolbar however you prefer, then set it to the [InputAccessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) property of the UITextField whose keyboard it should accompany. It will be automatically displayed above the keyboard whenever it appears.